# What is the purpose of Resolving model jre:call:zip:1.0.0?

Tags: java, eclipse

I try to run a Java program, I see:

> Resolving model jre:call:zip:1.0.0

[image]

Comment: Yeah I get the same thing...no idea...but would like to know...of course.

Comment: I think that it is something to do with the Code Recommenders plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in eclipse-> preferences -> java -> installed jre, you have JDK and not the JRE.
[image]